# Check if an s3 url exists

Tags: python, http, boto

I have the following url, which exists:

```
https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/premiere-avails/458ca3ce-c51e-4f69-8950-7af3e44f0a3d__chapter025.jpg
```

But this one does not:

```
https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/premiere-avails/459ca3ce-c51e-4f69-8950-7af3e44f0a3d__chapter025.jpg
```

Is there a way to check a url to see if it is valid, without downloading the file (it may be a 1GB file)? Note that I do not want to use `boto` to see if the key exists, I would like to use an `HTTP` request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
import httplib
from urlparse import urlparse

def url_exists(url):
    _, host, path, _, _, _ = urlparse(url)
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(host)
    conn.request('HEAD', path)
    return conn.getresponse().status < 400
```

Comment: `HEAD` request is the correct way, it avoids downloading the whole file.

Answer (score 1):

You could use curl.  The `--head` option would send a HEAD request rather than a GET so it would not return the body even if it did exist.

curl --head https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/premiere-avails/458ca3ce-c51e-4f69-8950-7af3e44f0a3d__chapter025.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the `requests` Python library, the function would look like this:

```
import requests

def check_url(url):
    """
    Checks if the S3 link exists.

    Parameters:
        url (str): link to check if exists.

    Returns:
        bool: True if exists, False otherwise
    """
    request = requests.head(url)
    if request.status_code == 200:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The `requests.head()` function returns a [`requests.Response()` object](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_response.asp) from which you can get a lot of different values. If you want to check if the request's status code is less than 400 you could use `request.ok == True` instead of comparing `request.status_code == 200`. Also, function to request the head—`requests.head()`—can also take on parameters such as a timeout; [docs for this function here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_head.asp).